# How do I set the width and height for charts? (for use with Visualizer plugin)

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have created a bunch of charts using the Visualizer Plugin for WordPress. ( https://sv.wordpress.org/plugins/visualizer/ )

It is possible to set `width` in both percent and in pixels for each chart using the Visualizer Plugin. Based on the first chart, I want to set `width` and `height` of all other charts when JavaScript loads...

Basically, I want to set the main chart to `100%` of the `width` and `height` to {x} pixels, and I want all other charts to have the same `width` and `height` as the main chart.

The generated `html` looks something like this...

```
<div id="chart-wrapper" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:600px;">
    <div id="visualizer-100"></div>
    <div id="visualizer-101"></div>
    <div id="visualizer-102"></div>
    <div id="visualizer-103"></div>
</div>
```

The charts must be set to the same location, so I set `position:absolute` on the visualizer-{x} `div`s. The visualizer `div`s are created by the plugin and it uses `SVG/HTML5` to create the charts for the `div`s it has created.

I tried this to set `width` and `height` of the `div`(s), but I don't understand why the `width` is set to: `0px`. **Can someone give me a hint / explain why?**

```
$.each(chart, function( chartname, index ) {

    //Visualizer-100 is the main chart
    var w = $("#visualizer-100").css('width'); 
    var h  = $("#visualizer-100").css('height');
    console.log(w); //Outputs 727px in console

    $("#visualizer-" + index)
        .css('position','absolute')
        .css('left','0px')
        .css('top','0px')
        .css('width', w)
        .css('height', h);

    console.log( $("#visualizer-" + index).css('height') );
    //outputs 0px. WHY????

}
```

**UPDATE:**
Question: Is your intent to place all of the visualizer-{x} child elements in the same location, at the upper left corner of the #chart-wrapper parent element? **Yes, this is because when I hover over any chart that chart is shown over the main chart (with a transparent background).**

Clarification (I wasn't trying to focus on either width or height. I want them both to work)

```
var w = $("#visualizer-100").css('width');
var h  = $("#visualizer-100").css('height');
console.log(w); //Outputs 727px in console
console.log(h); //Outputs 0px. WHY? The actual genereated height is 300px. This height is set by the Visualizer plugin. I've tried setting with both 300 and 300px in the plugin settings, but it does not seem to matter which I choose.

    $("#visualizer-" + index)
        .css('position','absolute')
        .css('left','0px')
        .css('top','0px')
        .css('width', w)
        .css('height', h);

console.log('width and height applied to #visualizer-' + index);
console.log( $("#visualizer-" + index).css('width') ); //727px correctly
console.log( $("#visualizer-" + index).css('height') ); //0px. Of course this is 0 because the origin is 0px, but why is the origin 0?
```

After some digging I see that widths are set correctly, but not height. It doesn't seem to retrieve the actual height value of the chart height but instead it retrieves 0px.

The html that is generated for a specific chart looks like this... (if it helps)

```
<div id="visualizer-100">
<div style="position: relative;">
<div dir="ltr" style="position: relative; width: 727px; height: 200px;">
<div aria-label="Ett diagram." style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<svg width="727" height="200" aria-label="Ett diagram." style="overflow: hidden;">
<defs id="defs">
<clipPath id="_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0"><rect x="58" y="38" width="669" height="124">
</rect>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="727" height="200" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
<g><rect x="58" y="38" width="669" height="124" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
<g clip-path="url(#_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0)"><g>
<rect x="58" y="161" width="669" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect>
<rect x="58" y="130" width="669" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="58" y="100" width="669" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="58" y="69" width="669" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect><rect x="58" y="38" width="669" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></rect></g>
<g><rect x="58" y="100" width="669" height="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000"></rect></g>
<g><path d="M125.3,100L258.9,117.22L392.5,106.765L526.0999999999999,-18.079999999999984L659.6999999999999,54.489999999999995" stroke="#afafaf" stroke-width="2" fill-opacity="1" fill="none"></path></g></g>
<g></g><g><g><g>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="125.3" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="3" fill="#222222" aria-hidden="true">2010</text>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="125.3" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2010</text></g></g>
<g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="258.9" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="3" fill="#222222" aria-hidden="true">2011</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="258.9" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2011</text></g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="392.5" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="3" fill="#222222" aria-hidden="true">2012</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="392.5" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2012</text></g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="526.0999999999999" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="3" fill="#222222" aria-hidden="true">2013</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="526.0999999999999" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2013</text></g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="659.6999999999999" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="3" fill="#222222" aria-hidden="true">2014</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="659.6999999999999" y="153.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">2014</text></g></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="55.75" y="165.7" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">-100</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="55.75" y="134.95" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">-50</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="55.75" y="104.2" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">0</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="55.75" y="73.45" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">50</text></g><g><text text-anchor="end" x="55.75" y="42.7" font-family="" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#444444">100</text></g></g></g><g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="392.5" y="185.2" font-family="" font-size="12" font-style="italic" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Jahr</text></g><g><text text-anchor="middle" x="12.45" y="100" font-family="" font-size="12" font-style="italic" transform="rotate(-90 12.45 100)" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Prozent in</text><text text-anchor="middle" x="26.7" y="100" font-family="" font-size="12" font-style="italic" transform="rotate(-90 26.7 100)" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#222222">Veränderung</text></g></g><g></g></svg><div aria-label="Data i diagrammet  i tabellform." style="position: absolute; left: -10000px; top: auto; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;"><table><thead><tr><th></th><th>Deutschland</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>2010</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>2011</td><td>-28</td></tr><tr><td>2012</td><td>-11</td></tr><tr><td>2013</td><td>192</td></tr><tr><td>2014</td><td>74</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div><div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 210px; left: 737px; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">0
</div>
<div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks ok, but you are logging the height at the end, a typo?

Comment: Is your intent to place all of the `visualizer-{x}` child elements in the same location, at the upper left corner of the `#chart-wrapper` parent element? Since you have defined its `position` as `relative`, all of the child (`#visualizer`) elements that have their `position` defined as `absolute` will be positioned in relation to the parent. And given that all of the children have: `position: absolute`, `left: 0px`, and `top: 0px`, they will all be placed at the top-left corner of `#chart-wrapper`. It sounds like that may be what you want, but just trying to help by double-checking.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what `style` attribute is ending up with the value zero? As @David points out, your question is focused on `width`, but in the code, `console.log` outputs the `height` property. Either way, I believe you will have to add more detail about how your code is interacting with the Visualizer Plugin to get to the bottom of the unexpected zero value. What you currently have doesn't provide enough context for us to help you answer that question.

Comment: @SeanMickey, forgive me for being unclear. Have updated and hope it makes sense... If it doesn't ask again :-)

Comment: @David - updated the question. I was mixing width and height that might have added to my own confusion ;-) But there is still an issue. I've updated with an attempty to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention in your posting what browser/viewer you are using to load your document, but my guess is that your unexpected zero `height` is at least partially related to your browser/viewer. To give you some comparison data, I copied your specific chart code into an `HTML5` document, loaded that into Chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 m (64-bit) on Windows, and the results were different:

- The `#visualizer-100` `div` has `height: 200px` and `width: 1333px`.
- The `<div dir="ltr" style="position: relative; width: 727px; height: 200px;">` element has `height: 200px` and `width: 727px`.
- The `<svg width="727" height="200" aria-label="Ett diagram." style="overflow: hidden;">` element has `height: 200px` and `width: 727px`.

But beyond any possible browser issues, the use of `SVG` is also part of the problem; in many ways it creates a document of one type embedded within a document of another (`SVG` within `HTML`). This is acceptable of course, but the rules for `SVG` styling are different than the rules for `HTML` styling. There are 2 key differences that are important for your document:

### SVG Doesn't Follow CSS Box Model Rules

The layout isn't based on a set of rectangles that structurally flow through the document and standard `CSS` properties such as: `border`, `padding`, `margin`, or `box-sizing` don't strictly apply to `SVG`. For reference, the `SVG` spec includes its own list of [SVG styling properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties).

### SVG Elements Don't Follow CSS Positioning Rules

`CSS` properties such as `position` and `z-index` stacking don't apply to `SVG` elements (but `display` and `overflow` are supported). The `position` property is a key aspect of your current `#visualizer-{x}` element layout; but since the `position` property (unfortunately) doesn't apply to the `SVG` element(s), that is where I suggest you start. There may be Visualizer Plugin options that do not generate `SVG` markup or you may be able to use the `SVG` specific style properties (referenced by the link above) to adjust your layout so that the `position` property is unnecessary.

Also, you may want to look at the [caniuse SVG support matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) to see if that  helps to clarify your options for moving forward.